# Compactness implies total boundedness in any topological vector space?

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I know that in a complete metric space,  compactness is equivalent to closedness and total boundedness. However, in an arbitrary topological vector space, I think compactness implies total boundedness. (The definition of total boundedness in any tvs is as in Rudin's functional analysis definition 3.19.) Is my judgement correct?

Comment: Are we all supposed to know what is Rudin's definition of total boundedness in topological vector spaces?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos - no, not **all** of us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows immediately from the definition. Let $E$ be compact and $V$ be a neighborhood of $0$. Then $(x+V)_{x \in E}$ is an open cover of $E$ so there is  a finite subcover $(x_i+V)_{1\leq i \leq n}$. Let $F=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ . Then $E \subset F+V$.